# How do call an array in a php file called by ajax request?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

The `sqlInfo` object that I'm passing into ajax request is:
[image]

*ajax request*

```
      var saveFields = $.ajax({
        url: '../P3_M3/ajax/saveform.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: sqlInfo,
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        },
        success: function (errorJSON) {
            console.log(errorJSON['error']);
        },
        complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus){
          console.log(`AJAX thinks edit save request was a ${textStatus}`);
          $(".form-edit").fadeOut(300);
        }
      });
```

This is how I usually call in `saveform.php`

```
$_POST['requestAction']; //gives me "save"
```

So how would I called `checked` or `unchecked` since they're an array?
Would this suffice:

```
$checkedArr = $_POST['checked'] //will this give me an array?
foreach($checkedArr as $key => $value){ //can I do this?
   echo "$key $value \n";
}
//Will this print?
// 0 1 
// 1 2 
//2 3
```

### Note

I've also read about `JSON.stringify`, is this the case where I should use it?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: @Mazz no I'm on a deadline so I'm kind of multitasking several tasks

Comment: @Mazz also my saveform.php is more complex than simply calling $_POST['checked']. It has a lot of abstractions so I kind of want to make it perfect to reduce debugging

Comment: checkout json_decode.

Answer (score 0):

On your html form just add a checkbox and give it a name, next you have to check if the checkbox is empty or not , see the example:

```
    $var = $_POST['checkbox'];
    if (empty($var)){
    //nothing here 
    } else {
    //run your script
    }
```